# Interpretation of scaled Schoenfeld residual for time dependent coefficient

Tags: survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate, schoenfeld-residuals

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/survival/vignettes/timedep.pdf

I've been following the vignette on implementing time dependent coefficient in addressing non proportional hazards in a cox proportional hazard model.

I'm specifically following section 4.1 in regards to the Step function and is having a hard time understanding the residual plot.

From the vignette, it appears the data was cut at 2 different time points (t=90, and t=180), until three groups. The residuals also appears wildly different at the specified cut points from the residual plot.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I interpret these plots and the different patterns in residual ?